# Как получить объект, представленный в строковом виде?

Tags: python

Например, есть экземпляр класса, представленный в виде строки - "<**main**.A at 0xb5d3f5ac>". Каким образом получить оригинальный экземпляр класса A из этой строки?

Comment: А зачем так мудровствовать?

Comment: Так получилось.

Comment: Я не просто из любопытства спросить, а чтобы понять что вы имеете ввиду и что можно предложить. Например, если вы хотите восстановить объект из логов после закрытия скрипта, ничего не выйдет

Comment: Я использую osc. Мне нужно перекинуть ссылку на экземпляр класса из одного скрипта в другой, так как вызвать функцию и передать параметром экземпляр посредством osc.sendMsg('/func_from_other_script', [my_object,], port=3002) я не могу, потому что sendMsg передает только простые объекты, типа int, str...

Comment: Вам нужен `pickle` :) Через него сериализуете объект, передадите и на другой стороне десериализуете

Comment: Да вот как раз пытаюсь...

Comment: Ну а что не получается? osc может bytes передавать?

Comment: Да тоже проблема вылазит - pickle пытается найти класс, который я сериализовал для десериализации в другом скрипте, ну а пути, естественно не совпадают, так как импортированы модули в разных скриптах и вылазит ImportError: No module named my_module при попытке десериализации.

Comment: завести один и тот же класс или импортировать его в оба скрипта? ну ок, еще вариант: передавать json / xml

Comment: Вот мне-то и нужно передать json размером в 40 метров. Поясню: это мобильное приложение. При старте грузит базу в 40 мегабайт. json.loads при таких размерах базы на мобиле работает порядка 14 секунд, что тормозит процесс загрузки приложения, а это не приемлемо. Загружать в отдельном потоке, используя Thread оказалось неудачным решением, так как приложение все равно тормозит, хотя по идее база грузится отдельным потоком. Было принято решение использовать osc и сервисы, что проблему тормозов решило. Приложение стартует с сервисом. Сервис грузит базу. Вопрос: как передать базу основному скрипту?

Comment: Варианты: 1) По частям? 2) Не в json, а в бинарном формате 3) Сжимать данные перед отправкой 4) Сделать прогрессбар, пока происходит загрузка

Comment: Дело в том, что ничто никуда не отправляется. Я читаю базу в переменную. Лучшего, чем перекинуть ссылку на экземпляр класса, который занимается загрузкой базы в сервисе, в основной скрипт посредством osc.sendMsg('/func_from_other_script', [my_object,], port=3002) и уже в функции func_from_other_script основного скрипта оперировать экземпляром, я не нашел. Но дело в том, что модуль, который занимается загрузкой базы импортируется в сервисе, а тот же модуль, который нужен для десериализации импортируется в основном скрипте. И pickle не может провести десериализацию, так как не находит модуль.

Comment: А вот передать объект как строку ( "<main.A at 0xb5d3f5ac>") - пожалуйста. Поэтому и  задал вопрос такой глупый.

Comment: `объект как строку ( "<main.A at 0xb5d3f5ac>") ` объект так не передать, когда вы объект передавали, у того вызвали `repr` и получившуюся строку отправили (`class Foo:pass  repr(Foo())
'<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000000002ADE908>') так что, не получится так объект передавать. Я не понимаю, почему нужно одним махом все передавать? Почему в цикле не сделать передачу по частям, а на другой стороне собрать

Comment: В смысле, по частям? Я кроме строкового типа, типа int и bytes  ничего другого передать не могу: ни словари, ни картежи... К тому же,  osc.sendMsg имеет ограничение на длину передаваемой строки.

Comment: Ту же строку/байты можно по частям отправлять. `'abcd'[:2], 'abcd'[2:]` дадут `('ab', 'cd')`. osc.sendMsg к какому модулу относится? Хочу посмотреть документацию/код. `from kivy.lib import osc `? И какое ограничение на длину? Происходит какая-либо ошибка?

Comment: from kivy.lib import osc

Comment: Но это сторонний модуль в общем.